# Kibana unwanted thousand-seperator

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm just messing around with Kibana (4.1.1) and for some reason Kibana separates all my integer fields (>999) with a ",".
I specified a mapping in Elasticsearch and the fields in question are definitely integers. They are shown in Kibana as numbers and behave exactly like numbers (I can, for instance, set a range in a visualization).
Thanks a bunch.

Edit:
Just to clarify, this is merely a cosmetic issue.

Edit2:
Ideally I would like to be able to specify integer-representations on a field-by-field basis.
[image: Kibana411_integerFormatting]

Comment: I don't understand the question... You mean you don't want it to show commas in legit numbers? Or are you saying you want it to be properly localized for your local? If the latter, see https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1171

Comment: Sorry, thought the attached image would make it clear.
Ideally I would like to specify thousands-seperators on a field-by-field basis. Having Port-Numbers split by commas is all sorts of wrong and confusing.
But I'll settle for whatever removes the commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kibana 4.1 released a feature which enables the type of [field-level formatting](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1543) you are looking for. You specify the formatting rules under "Settings --> Indices --> your index". Then edit the field you want to customize.

Comment: Just to add further clarification to hubbardr and AlainCollins (who commented below). I ran into this cosmetic issue when trying to display __port__ numbers from log data without comma separators.  i.e. Port 5601 displays as 5,601. I updated the field in my index pattern to type __number__ and changed the format to 00.[000] from 0,0.[000]. ref: http://numeraljs.com/#format

Answer (score 2):

This is a new feature in kibana.

You can change the behavior of any field by going to Settings->Indices, selecting your index pattern, and then clicking the grey Edit button for your field.  There will be a Format option there.